# my SetTimeout is not auto submitting my button

Tags: javascript, php, settimeout

I have a code like

```
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
setTimeout('document.test.submit()',1000);
</SCRIPT>
```

I follow the tutorials on how to do a settimeout function but it is not working with my php code.. my Whole code looks like this..

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
setTimeout('document.test.submit()',1000);
</SCRIPT>
</head>
```

and my php looks like this..

```
                echo "<form name=\"asd\" id=\"form1\" action=\"PostTest1.php\" method=\"post\" >";


                    echo "<tr><td>";
                    echo $row['Description'] . "<br>";
                    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Answer\" value=\"A\"> A.)" . $row['Ans1'];
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Answer\" value=\"B\"> B.)" . $row['Ans2'];
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Answer\" value=\"C\"> C.)" . $row['Ans3'];
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Answer\" value=\"D\"> D.)"  . $row['Ans4'];
                    echo "<br>";

                echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" name=\"submit\">";

                    echo "</td></tr>";

                echo "</form>";
```

My button is not auto clicking.. Thank you for the advance help.. :)
(Sorry for my grammar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`setTimeout(document.getElementById("form1").submit(),1000);` alternatively, you could also do this: `setTimeout(document.asd.submit(),1000);` since you've named your form.

You need to find the correct element to submit, `document.test` is not valid in your supplied scenario.

**EDIT:** You need to remove the name attribute from your submit button as when you call `.submit()` it is finding that element, rather than submitting the form like you'd expect.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/yKG3U/

Comment: I think its because of the if statement?? my form is in an if statement.. maybe thats the cause?

Comment: Here is a working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/yKG3U/ you need to remove the `name="submit"` from your submit button as the form is finding that element when you call `.submit()` rather than submitting the form as you'd expect.

Comment: Sir.. im so greatful you helped me.. it worked.. Thank you very much.. :)

Comment: Not a problem :) Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout needs a function to call and the timeout.

you can do:

```
 setTimeout(my_func(), 1000);
function my_func(){
  document.getElementById("id_form").submit();
}
```

That way should work.